# Is it possible to access full index scope at sidebar in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have created ActiveAdmin administration interface for `Bill` model in my application, and want to display statistic information in sidebar on index and filtered searches (like total amount of current filtered bills). In sidebar seaction I have access to `bills` relation like that:

```
sidebar do
  bills.sum(:amount)
end
```

`bills` correctly scoped with current filters: date, number etc.

But 'bills' relation contains only 30 records (which displayed on page, 30 is default pagination size), but in total it's more than 300. How can I get "unpaged" relation for current filtered bills (with current selected filters)?

Answer (score 3):

Get it myself, I can use `bills.limit(nil)`, which override current page selection in relation, and returns full scope.